# Castle Windsor: Get all names of registered components for a specific interface

Tags: castle-windsor, factory

I have written a new FactoryComponentSelector which is able to resolve an instance of a specific interface by its name. So far so good. However, when it comes to configuration in the business part of our application I need a list of all names for a given interface out of the container.

Let's say we have the following registration:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

container.Register(Component.For<ITypedFactoryComponentSelector>().ImplementedBy<CreateByNameComponentSelector>());
container.Register(Component.For<IProviderFactory>().AsFactory(c => c.SelectedWith<CreateByNameComponentSelector>()));

container.Register(Component.For<IProvider>().ImplementedBy<FirstProvider>().Named("First"));
container.Register(Component.For<IProvider>().ImplementedBy<SecondProvider>().Named("Second"));
container.Register(Component.For<IProvider>().ImplementedBy<ThirdProvider>().Named("Third"));
```

Is there a way to ask the container for a list of names for all registered components implementing the interface IProvider?

Answer (score 8):

```
var handlers = container.Kernel.GetHandlers(typeof(IProvider));

handlers.Select(h=>h.ComponentModel.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<IProvider> providers = container.ResolveAll<IProvider>();
```

One remark - as Windsor [docs](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Three-Calls-Pattern.ashx#Call_two_-_Resolve__1) say:

> " When you're using ResolveAll be aware that it has a little bit different semantics than Resolve. It will return all resolvable components assignable to specified type, not just those that have the type registered as one of their services."